# Pass parameter to function frmo another function call

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to pass a parameter to a function through another function call.

```
function cursorViaFun(b){
                map.off('click');
                map.on('click', funcToBeCalled);
            }
```

In the map.on method i need to be able to call a function that would be named funcToBeCalled+(value of b) or through which i can pass b as a parameter   map.on('click', funcToBeCalled(b));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either do it with a closure:

```
function cursorViaFun(b){
    map.off('click');
    map.on('click', function(){
       funcToBeCalled(b)
    });
}
```

Or with the bind-syntax (not available in all browsers) :

```
function cursorViaFun(b){
    map.off('click');
    map.on('click', funcToBeCalled.bind(this, b)); // the first parameter identifies what 
                                                   // this will point inside the function, 
                                                   // here I'm just passing the current 
                                                   // value
}
```